# Ivy tool tips and ctrl-d brining up unwanted documentation

Tags: key-bindings, ivy, tooltip

Using emacs 30, I have an issue where when an ivy tooltip pops up, pressing <kbd>ctrl-d</kbd> causes documentation to show up instead of the expected deleting of a character. I've not been able to determine how to unbind ctrl-d for this case. I've tried

```
(with-eval-after-load 'tooltip-mode
  (define-key lsp-mode-map (kbd "C-d") nil)
)
```

with various modes (lsp-mode, ivy-mode, tooltip-mode) all with no success. How do I unbind <kbd>ctrl-d</kbd> in this situation?

[image]

Comment: Which command is `C-d` bound to? E.g. what does `C-h k C-d` (`M-x describe-key RET C-d`) say?

Comment: I've not been able to get that info since as soon as the minibuffer has the focus the tooltip goes away and `describe-key` just gives the definition of the expected `c-d`

Comment: Bisect your init file, to find the culprit.

Comment: @Silfheed BTW, the tooltip looks more like that of [`company`](http://company-mode.github.io/) than something out of [`ivy`](https://github.com/abo-abo/swiper/).